# How to call my insert, delete, and search functions that I have created in C++

Tags: c++, function, search, insert, binary-search-tree

So, I have the below code where I created functions to insert, delete, and search numbers in a binary search tree.

My functions look one (as far as I know), but when I try to call my insert function, it tells me "Use of undeclared identifier "insert"".

I'm not sure what's going on or where I'm messing up here, but I ned it to be able to add a list of numbers (3,1,5,7,9,2), delete to of those, then search for a number.

I'm currently stuck and could use another set of eyes to help me catch what I'm missing, thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
 
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
 
class Node {
public:
    int value;
    Node* left;       // left child
    Node* right;      // right child
    Node* p;          // parent
    Node(int data) {
        value = data;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
        p = NULL;
    }
    ~Node() {
    }
    int d() {
        return value;
    }
    void print() {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
};
 
void insert(Node* insert_node, Node* tree_root) {
    if (insert_node->d() < tree_root->d()) {
        if (tree_root->left == NULL) {
            tree_root->left = insert_node;
            insert_node->p = tree_root;
        }
        else {
            insert(insert_node, tree_root->left);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (tree_root->right == NULL) {
            tree_root->right = insert_node;
            insert_node->p = tree_root;
        }
        else {
            insert(insert_node, tree_root->right);
        }
    }
}
 
void delete_node(int value, Node* tree_root) {
    if (value < tree_root->d()) {
        if (tree_root->left == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            delete_node(value, tree_root->left);
        }
    }
    else if (value > tree_root->d()) {
        if (tree_root->right == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            delete_node(value, tree_root->right);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (tree_root->left == NULL && tree_root->right == NULL) {
            if (tree_root->p->left == tree_root) {
                tree_root->p->left = NULL;
            }
            else {
                tree_root->p->right = NULL;
            }
            delete tree_root;
        }
        else if (tree_root->left == NULL) {
            if (tree_root->p->left == tree_root) {
                tree_root->p->left = tree_root->right;
            }
            else {
                tree_root->p->right = tree_root->right;
            }
            delete tree_root;
        }
        else if (tree_root->right == NULL) {
            if (tree_root->p->left == tree_root) {
                tree_root->p->left = tree_root->left;
            }
            else {
                tree_root->p->right = tree_root->left;
            }
            delete tree_root;
        }
        else {
            Node* temp = tree_root->right;
            while (temp->left != NULL) {
                temp = temp->left;
            }
            tree_root->value = temp->value;
            delete_node(temp->value, tree_root->right);
        }
    }
}
 
Node* search(int value, Node* tree_root) {
    if (value < tree_root->d()) {
        if (tree_root->left == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        else {
            return search(value, tree_root->left);
        }
    }
    else if (value > tree_root->d()) {
        if (tree_root->right == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        else {
            return search(value, tree_root->right);
        }
    }
    else {
        return tree_root;
    }
}
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    //USE THIS TO TEST INSERT FUNCTION
    insert(2);       //ERROR MESSAGE HERE
    insert(1);       // ""     ""      ""
    Insert(4);       // ""     ""      ""
    Insert(5);       // ""     ""      ""
    Insert(9);       // ""     ""      ""
    Insert(3);       // ""     ""      ""
    Insert(6);       // ""     ""      ""
    Insert(7);       // ""     ""      ""
    Insert(10);      // ""     ""      ""
    Insert(12);      // ""     ""      ""
    Insert(11);      // ""     ""      ""
    Insert(4);       // ""     ""      ""
    
 
    //PRINT TREE IN ORDER
    PrintTree(tree_root);
    return 0;
```

Comment: How is `insert` declared? What are its arguments?

Comment: That's not the error you should be getting. It should be more like "[too few arguments to function 'void insert(Node*, Node*)'](https://godbolt.org/z/brf9o3P9q)". Are you sure you are compiling this exact code? Did you save the file?

Answer (score 0):

```
void insert(Node* insert_node, Node* tree_root)
```

This is your declared `insert` function. As you can see here, you declared this function as taking two parameters, two pointers.

```
  insert(2);       //ERROR MESSAGE HERE
```

> I'm not sure what's going on or where I'm messing up here,

What's going on here is that you're calling a function called `insert()`, passing it one parameter, an integer value. That, of course, doesn't come anywhere close to passing two pointer parameters.

Since there is no declared function named "insert" that takes an integer parameter (or something that an integer value can be converted to), your compiler is returning error message. That's what's going on here.